# How can I prevent IntelliJ IDEA from autocolapsing folders

Tags: intellij-idea

I use intellIJ. Sometimes I have two packages, A and B, that are nested such that A contains B and nothing else. When this happens then the folder structure on the left displays them like this:

[image]

I don't like how it groups A.B together into a single tree node. Is there a setting to prevent IntelliJ from doing this?

(I've googled around a bit and dug through the settings menu and I'm not seeing anything but may'be I've missed it.)

Comment: I guess you were using caps `A` and `B` just for the purpose of example? Convention is of course lower case... `a` and `b`...

Comment: Not only do I typically use upper case package names, I also make sure that they are always a single character long.

Comment: Don't forget to use underscore `_` occasionally too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the gear icon on top of the project panel and look for "Compact empty middle packages"

Comment: Always glad to help a brother IntelliJ user out :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to do this by default for all projects?